# Attribute scope is disabled. How can I change it?

Tags: magento2, attributes, scope-switcher

I want to translate the attribute *SKU* in product detail pages. I've set the default label to *Artikelnummer (NL)* and translated the label under **Manage Labels**.

Still... in customer view it only shows the dutch language in different store views. Therefore I want to change the scope to **STORE**. As you see in the image below, that option is disabled.

[image: Screen of disabled scope option]

How do I get the translations under **Manage Labels** to show in different store views?

Comment: not sure what the problem is, but changing the scope will not solve your issue. Also changing the scope of the sku can lead to problems.

Comment: @Marius I assumed changing the scope to **STORE VIEW** would make Magento use the translated labels I've entered under **Manage Labels**. How am I supposed to translate the SKU (Default label) then?

Comment: translate it using the translation files.

Comment: @marius Sadly, that doesn't work

Comment: @Marius Can you explain why changing the scope of the SKU can lead to problems? Because my client needs that to identify in which country the product is sold. So he needs to have a SKU 1234-EN, 1234-NL, 1234-DE. But those SKU's are the same product in the backend.

Comment: @FrankGroot I cannot predict what can happen if you chance the scope for SKU. All I know is that the SKU is that one SKU means 1 product. Also, not sure if you can actually change the scope because the sku is not kept in the eav tables. It is kept directly in the `catalog_product_entity` table.